# Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/send, 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am following [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) to generate a send link dialog. This is still under development, so I am using localhost.

```
FB.ui({method: 'send',link: 'https://www.facebook.com/me2spage/'});
```

All other fb sdk related api calls are working. Only the above gives an error in console.

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/send?access_token=...... in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'
```

[image: UI keeps loading]

UI keeps loading.

May I know what wrong I am doing here. Thanks.